# libcurl, How to attach a different callback function for each handle?

Tags: c++, libcurl

libcurl allows you to create a "handle" for each file transfer. It allows you to specify a URL for the file and a callback function that will receive bits and pieces of the file as its retrieved from the URL. What if you wanted a different callback for each handle? How would you go about doing this? Keep in mind that the callbacks must be non-member functions (or static member functions).

One way would be to manually type up a different call back for each of your handles, such as:

```
size_t callback1(void* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmem, void* userp);
size_t callback2(void* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmem, void* userp);
size_t callback3(void* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmem, void* userp);
// ...etc
```

This works, unless you are creating handles *dynamically*. Consider a function such as this:

```
void f(){
  CURLHandle handle = curl_easy_init();
  // set the url to some random url
  // set a *unique* call back for this handle
}
```

How would you do this? The solution would be easy if you could use member functions as callbacks, but you cannot.

Comment: [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) might come in handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since curl is C you will have to do this the C way. The callback needs to be a static. To access your class variables you should pass a parameter to the callback (see [CURLOPT_WRITEDATA](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html)). This can also be a "this" object or a pointer to a std::string I suppose.. See the [getinmemory.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) example.

Comment: Thank you, I used CURLOPT_WRITEDATA option passed in the object (this).